# What is the most practical way of ensuring an AWS DynamoDB doesn't go over free limits or you getting charged?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use a DynamoDB (specifically with boto3) but I want to avoid getting charged? Most practical way to do this? What sort of usage surpasses free limits?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) is intended as a means of trying AWS services. It is not provided to run production systems.

The Free Tier is a pricing discount provided each month, either for the first 12 months of your AWS Account or, for some services, for every month even after 12 months.

If your usage goes beyond the free usage amount for a service, **you will be charged the normal cost of the service**.

The free usage tier for DynamoDB provides:

- 25GB of storage (Value: $6.25)
- 25 Read Capacity Units (Value: Under $0.01)
- 25 Write Capacity Units (Value: Under $0.02)

So, the free tier is only saving you $6.28/month at best. If you go a little over this amount, you're probably not going to be spending much.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS free tier page has extensive information on the 60 or so services which provide a free tier, including DynamoDB. You can find the free tier services page [here](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=categories%23featured).

As far as avoiding going over DynamoDB free tier limits, there’s a number of potential ways you could handle this. One way might be to use CloudWatch alarms to notify you that you’re approaching the limits, and you could take action when you receive the notification. Another way would be to use CloudWatch events to trigger a Lambda function that sets read and write capacity to 1 when you’re near the limits and thus minimizing your potential overage. In any event, you’ll have to decide what you want to do when you hit those limits, and handle it accordingly.